# A senior developer on my team tells me that writing SQL commands like this is safe "because it's parameterized", but I don't see how

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-injection

I'm writing some CRUD functions for media associated with certain products. To delete many records, I've been told to write the query as follows:

```
dataContext.ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM ProductMedia WHERE ProductId = {0}", productId);
```

He says this is safe from SQL injection because it's 'parameterized'. I don't agree, but I also don't know a better way.

How do you protect from SQL injection when writing commands in this way?

Comment: Did you read the docs for `ExecuteCommand`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Why don't you agree? Can you explain to me how the parametrized query is susceptible to injection?

Comment: `ExecuteCommand("DELETE FROM ProductMedia WHERE ProductId = {0}", productId)` is parametrized and safe. `ExecuteCommand(string.Format("DELETE FROM ProductMedia WHERE ProductId = {0}", productId))` is not.

Comment: I've read the docs now, thank you for that. I just thought you might be able to pass something in like `"1 OR 1=1; UPDATE SensitiveRecords SET Password = ''"`.

Comment: @Yahtzei You can pass that. It will delete the product whose Id equals `"1 OR 1=1; UPDATE SensitiveRecords SET Password = ''"`.

Comment: As a last resort, you can always check [what it does](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/DataContext.cs,6d9aaf907e82e81f) that method checking the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He says this is safe from SQL injection because it's 'parameterized'.

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand?view=netframework-4.8), the code in your question is perfectly valid and will be parameterised correctly:

> The syntax for the command is almost the same as the syntax used to
>   create an ADO.NET DataCommand. The only difference is in how the
>   parameters are specified. Specifically, you specify parameters by
>   enclosing them in braces ({…}) and enumerate them starting from 0. The
>   parameter is associated with the equally numbered object in the
>   parameters array.

It is essentially a wrapper - and it takes care of creating the necessary `SqlParameter` objects and assigning values to them. Other ORMs (like PetaPoco) have similar mechanisms.

Generally, the thing you want to avoid is **string concatenation** (or something that is effectively concatenation - like `string.Format`) - which this solution does not use. String concatenation is *almost always* open to SQL Injection. *But, again, the code in your question is fine.*